# Prevent auto-hide setting from syncing across Windows 8 computers

Tags: windows-8

Here's my situation

- I play iRacing in windowed mode on my desktop, using all of my screen space, so I enable auto-hiding of my task bar to give me the bottom portion of my screen to the game
- I then stop playing iRacing but often forget to re-disable auto-hiding of my task bar
- Then I'll later get on my laptop, login, and my auto-hide task bar setting will be on despite my laptop previously having it turned off (apparently Windows 8 syncs this across Live accounts)
- I then have to manually disable auto-hide on my laptop

I would rather my laptop never receive/sync this setting. I never want my auto-hide taskbar to be enabled on my laptop. How can I prevent this from happening?

Both the desktop and laptop are using Windows 8 and are logging in to the same Live account. I do *not* want to run iRacing in full-screen. I prefer it to be run in windowed mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure what is synced on the PC Settings screen.

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to get to settings then select `Sync your settings`. Set `Desktop Personalization` to `Off` to not sync the taskbar settings.

[image]

Comment: In windows 8.1 it's now hidden away in Windows+I, change PC settings, OneDrive, Sync settings.
Or from the start page type sync and click on 'sync settings'.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and change the setting and find the event that indicates the change, then you can right click and jump to the registry location; changing the permissions to be read only should make the setting never change again, not even by you.